# Simple button to close layer div using css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Just can't find the answer to this.

I have a div in my webpage, above on a different layer. I simply want to have a button or  tag inside this div which will hide it. I have tried:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
 myFunction()
 {
 document.getElementById("corporate_background").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>aajhahaksha</p>
<div id="corporate_background">
<a href="javascript:myFunction()">Close</a> 
<P>content...</P>
</div>
</body>
```

Could someone please show me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. The simplest things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
 function myFunction()
 {
 document.getElementById("corporate_background").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>aajhahaksha</p>
<div id="corporate_background">
<a href="javascript:myFunction()">Close</a> 
<P>content...</P>
</div>
</body>
```

This is just because you didn't define myFunction() as a function .

Next time, open your debugger with F12, and see what it is saying... !

Answer (score 0):

You missed out declaring your function at the beginning

```
myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById("corporate_background").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
}
```

You should declare using the keyword `function`.

```
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById("corporate_background").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
}
```

You should probably use an event listener on your anchor also instead of using inline javascript. No harm just best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
      function myFunction()
      {
        document.getElementById("corporate_background").style.display='none';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>aajhahaksha</p>
      <div id="corporate_background">
        <a href="javascript:myFunction()">Close</a> 
        <P>content...</P>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't paid attention, corrected and added the function keyword. Thanks @SushiiBalboha :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanna do is hide the content, so you can hide content like this,

Make the button ;

```
<button id="btn" name="button">Hide content</button>
```

By clicking the button it wil hide the div `corporate_background`

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $('#corporate_background').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```